# Axio Request return Network error if url 'localhost" and okay if use IP Address on VPS only(digital ocean)?

Tags: javascript, apache, http, vue.js, axios

this is my axios code to send POST Request

```
 axios.post('/api/login',userData)
        .then(res =>{
            const {token} = res.data.data;
            localStorage.setItem('jwtToken',token);
            setAuthToken(token);
            const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
            dispatch("setCurrentUser",decoded);
            resolve(res)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            commit(GET_ERRORS,err.response.data.error);
            reject(new Error(err));
            }
        );
```

the error only return **NETWORK ERROR :: CONN REFUSED** on cosole.log(err). when using "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" as Baseurl. but its return fine when using my "IP Address". and this is only happen in VPS, i using on my local machine everything normal.

my header setting for BaseURL

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:'+window.location.port+'/';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open a remotely hosted App (e.g. on Digital Ocean) from your machine, "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" refer to your local machine and not the remote HTTP Server. That local machine is not listening for connections and hence the client connection is being refused.

As far as I understand your setup, the API is hosted at the same location as your WebApp. Therefore you don't need to set any `baseURL` for Axios.

Removing the line

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:'+window.location.port+'/';
```

should solve your problem.